# lwp-rget changes file format automatically to .bin?

Tags: filesystems, file-management, html, perl

I'm trying to recursively get an html page to get everything that's there and save it to my directory.

Lwp-rget from perl allows me to do this but I'm having the problem that its getting all the files and changing them from `.rpm`, `.xml`, `.html`, etc to `.bin`.

I've been trying to maybe use the `--keepext=application/xml` or any type, but it continues to save the file as `.bin`.

Is there a way I can stop the auto formatting?